# having issue in my cart php after session login?

Tags: mysql

```
 Here is my cart code:
    if($_SESSION['SES_NAME'] && is_array($_SESSION['cart']))
       {
    if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
                    //echo $_SESSION['cart'];
                    echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td>Serial</td><td>Name</td><td>Image</td><td>Kg</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Amount</td><td>Options</td></tr>';
                    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
                    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                        $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
                        $pname=get_product_name($pid);
                        $pimage=get_image($pid);
                        $price=get_price($pid);
                        $total=get_order_total();                                   
                        $sql=mysql_query("insert into cart (uname,pid,pinfo,price,quantity,total) values ('".$_SESSION['SES_NAME']."','".$pid."','".$pname."','".$price."','".$q."','".$total."')");
 }
}
                ?>
```

Note:
I am facing problem with my db, First time user add the product in cart,it  goes to insertion, again same user gives continue cart with another product it adds three value into db?check this[image]

Comment: do `print_r($_SESSION['cart'])` and see what it consists.

Comment: It is giving correct  product id only, session login person, adds two product means, how to write mysql query here and I want to  update the product parameter  also for ex quantity, Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 1
            [qty] => 1
            [prosize] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 4
            [qty] => 1
            [prosize] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [productid] => 2
            [qty] => 1
            [prosize] => 5
        )

)

Comment: suchit? what is the problem here?how to bring this. where to write the insert query? more over  i want to update the quanity also, for that basically I want to insert the user session cart value to database, where to write the insert query? help me with my code

Comment: it has 3 products that is why it is making three entries.What you want? when your insert completes `unset` the current cart data.

Comment: Yes , see my insert query, where to write the  insert query if user has 2 or 3 or 5 with different product id, here it shows different product id only, I stuck with my insert

Comment: first before insert do: `select * from cart where pid=$pid` for the given user if returns a record then update it otherwise insert it.

Comment: suchit, you can see my db I am updating my db with user registered email id, now bala@vkacademy.in has two entry if  i write update query, it updates to all two entry, kindly guide me . I hope u understand my need , I  proper insert and update of my cart after session login with session name,

Comment: could  you write for me? unable to trigger that? like this i have to start  if($pid) with complete insert and update than I can manage my self

Comment: see the below answer and let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: ok i am embedding , thanks lot,  where to put this unset($_SESSION['cart']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** PLEASE START USING `mysqli` or `pdo`.

*Not TESTED* but Try to follow something like this:

```
 <?php 
    if($_SESSION['SES_NAME'] && is_array($_SESSION['cart']))
    {
        if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
            //echo $_SESSION['cart'];
            echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td>Serial</td><td>Name</td><td>Image</td><td>Kg</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Amount</td><td>Options</td></tr>';
            $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
            for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
                $pname=get_product_name($pid);
                $pimage=get_image($pid);
                $price=get_price($pid);
                $total=get_order_total();
                $sql="select * from cart where pid=$pid and uname='".$_SESSION['SES_NAME']."'";
                $res=mysql_query($sql);
                $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                if($num_rows > 0){
                    $rst = mysql_fetch_array ( $res, MYSQL_ASSOC );
                    $sql=" update cart set quantity =".$q+$rst['quantity']." where pkey=".$rst['pkey'];//you can add multiple columns to update
                }else{
                $sql=mysql_query("insert into cart (uname,pid,pinfo,price,quantity,total) values ('".$_SESSION['SES_NAME']."','".$pid."','".$pname."','".$price."','".$q."','".$total."')");
                }

                 //run the sql here
                }
        }
    }
        ?>
```

Comment: how update the cart when user gives update cart to db . correct me ,if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
 if($_SESSION['SES_NAME']!='')
 {
 $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
  for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
   $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
   $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
   $prosize=$_REQUEST['product_size_'.$pid];
   $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['prosize']=$prosize;
   $total=get_price($pid)*$q*$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['prosize'];
   $sql_update = mysql_query("update cart set total =".$total." where pkey=".$_SESSION['rst']."");
   }
 }
 }